# Codemirror preview - not in a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

i am trying to do the exact same as in this example, only, the code should not be printet in an iframe, but in a div.

http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html

This does not work... i need a different approach.

```
$("#codeMirrorTextarea").keyup(function () {
     $("#div").html($(this).val());
});
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using plain vanilla JS:

```
t = document.getElementById('code');
t.addEventListener('input',function(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = t.value;
});
```

Using the oninput event handler adds support to non-keyboard devices as well [as pointed out here](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9QUL/)

Edit:
Code using CodeMirror:

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").each(function (i) {
        editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
             lineNumbers: true
        });
    });
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=editor.getValue();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/b9QUL/36/)
[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/b9QUL/37/) that updates code as well.

The editor.getValue() has been used in the [example link](http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html) you provided.

[CodeMirror's API for usage of getValue() and more methods](http://codemirror.net/manual.html#api)

Comment: Hi, issnt that what i am trying?

The problem is, that i want it to work with Codemirror

I've come so far, that i know i need a Method called getCode() But i cant find any simple examples.

Comment: I don't really know jQuery, so I've answered your problem with vanilla JS. The method you speak of; is that a jQuery method?

Edit: Your code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/b9QUL/1/) for me.

Comment: There, CodeMirror is breaking your textarea. It makes it divs and pres and other tags. I'll look around and see if I can help you. Could you give me a link to where they explain how you write it to an iframe or something?

Comment: I could kiss you no matter what sex you are! Thanks :)

Comment: A few months have passed the 10 years after you posted this. The Updated demos you provided do not display the output. Since I did not see it when first published, not certain as to why. I grabbed the full source and found out that the "editors not defined"
If you are still around by chance, it would be cool if you could check in on this and give another update. Thanks.